# Is there a way to attach some arbitary data to a Sinch call?

Tags: android, webrtc, sinch

I'm trying to get Sinch to get work with an app that we're making. I was wondering if there is a way to attach some miscellaneous data to the call and have it delivered to the callee?
The attached data will be user specific information such as Name, Photo, etc. so we can display a proper view on callee's side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, add headers when you make a call. and on callEstablished event those will be available.